# Latex tikzpicture space between data and frame

Tags: latex, pgfplots

I have a problem with a graphic I created in Latex. If the graphic has few data entries, then everything looks great. The distance between the border and the first and last data point fits. Then it looks like this:

[image: LatexGraficLookingGood]

However, the more entries the graph receives, the greater the distance between the first and the last data point to the frame. This looks like this again:

[image: LatexGraficLookingBad]

The code to my graphic looks like this:

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed,tlabel/.style={yshift=2pt,above right,font=\small}]
    \begin{axis}[
        clip=false,
        axis line style={draw=none},
        legend style={at={(1.15,-0.1)},anchor=south west},
        reverse legend,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 15,
        xbar,
        bar width=2.5pt,
        xlabel = Label1,
        ylabel = Label2,
        symbolic y coords = {
            Coordinate1,
            Coordinate2,
        },
        y dir = reverse,
        y=0.7cm,
        xtick = {0,5,10,15},
        xtick pos = bottom,
        ytick = data,
        ytick pos = right,
        yticklabel pos = right,
    ]
        \addplot[draw=red!80!white,fill=red!80!white] coordinates {
            (10,Coordinate1)
            (5,Coordinate2)
        };
        \addplot[draw=blue!80!white,fill=blue!80!white,point meta=explicit symbolic,nodes near coords] coordinates {
            (5,Coordinate1)
            (10,Coordinate2)
        };
        \legend{1, 2}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Maybe someone of you has an idea what could be the reason that the distance grows with the number of entries and how I can prevent this? thanks in advance!

EDIT:
It was asked to provide a minimal example. Therefore now follows a minimal example with 2 graphics:

```
\documentclass[
11pt, 
a4paper, 
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed,tlabel/.style={yshift=2pt,above right,font=\small}]
        \begin{axis}[
            clip=false,
            axis line style={draw=none},
            legend style={at={(1.15,-0.2)},anchor=south west},
            reverse legend,
            xmin = 0,
            xmax = 15,
            xbar,
            bar width=2.5pt,
            xlabel = Label,
            ylabel = Label,
            symbolic y coords = {
                content1, 
                content2,
                content3,
                content4
            },
            y dir = reverse,
            y=0.7cm,
            xtick = {1,2,3,4},
            xtick pos = bottom,
            ytick = data,
            ytick pos = right,
            yticklabel pos = right,
    

]
            \addplot[draw=red!80!white,fill=red!80!white] coordinates {
                (1,content1)
                (2,content2)
                (3,content3)
                (4,content4)
            };
            \addplot[draw=blue!80!white,fill=blue!80!white,point meta=explicit symbolic,nodes near coords] coordinates {
                (4,content1)
                (3,content2)
                (2,content3)
                (1,content4)
            };
            \legend{label1, label2}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[framed,tlabel/.style={yshift=2pt,above right,font=\small}]
        \begin{axis}[
            clip=false,
            axis line style={draw=none},
            legend style={at={(1.15,-0.2)},anchor=south west},
            reverse legend,
            xmin = 0,
            xmax = 15,
            xbar,
            bar width=2.5pt,
            xlabel = Label,
            ylabel = Label,
            symbolic y coords = {
                content1, 
                content2,
                content3,
                content4,
                content5,
                content6,
                content7,
                content8,
                content9,
                content10,
                content11,
                content12,
                content13,
                content14,
                content15,
                content16,
                content17,
                content18,
                content19,
                content20
            },
            y dir = reverse,
            y=0.7cm,
            xtick = {1,2,3,4},
            xtick pos = bottom,
            ytick = data,
            ytick pos = right,
            yticklabel pos = right,
        ]
            \addplot[draw=red!80!white,fill=red!80!white] coordinates {
                (1,content1)
                (2,content2)
                (3,content3)
                (4,content4)
                (1,content5)
                (2,content6)
                (3,content7)
                (4,content8)
                (1,content9)
                (2,content10)
                (3,content11)
                (4,content12)
                (4,content13)
                (4,content14)
                (4,content15)
                (4,content16)
                (4,content17)
                (4,content18)
                (4,content19)
                (4,content20)
            };
            \addplot[draw=blue!80!white,fill=blue!80!white,point meta=explicit symbolic,nodes near coords] coordinates {
                (4,content1)
                (3,content2)
                (2,content3)
                (1,content4)
                (1,content5)
                (2,content6)
                (3,content7)
                (4,content8)
                (1,content9)
                (2,content10)
                (3,content11)
                (4,content12)
                (4,content13)
                (4,content14)
                (4,content15)
                (4,content16)
                (4,content17)
                (4,content18)
                (4,content19)
                (4,content20)
            };
            \legend{label1, label2}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [mre]

Comment: I added some code that generates two grafics with dummydata, hope that workes as a minimal example